# Can I convert a php $_POST variable into a jquery variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to know can I convert a php $_POST variable into a jquery variable. I have php variable below:

```
<?php  $postduration  = $_POST['durationChosen']; ?>
```

Can I convert the php variable above into a jquery variable?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a JavaScript variable, or something else?

Comment: Yeah sorry I should of said Javascript variable. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I just want to make sure that what you really want is to use the $_POST variable in javascript, I just upvoted your question it had no reason at all to be downvoted, all the answers below seem to be what you need DaveRandom and Romanulus have a better explanation on how it works

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you answers, I need to reach a reputation of 15 to upvote answers but when I do reach this I will upvote all answers. Thank You all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, of course!

Just write/output your PHP code right into your JavaScript ... block.

Kinda like this:

```
<script>
    var myVar = <? echo $postduration; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: just a heads up, you forgot the quotation marks.  var myVar = "<? echo $postduration ?>";

Comment: @redmoon7777 that would depend on the type of data

Answer (score 4):

```
var durationChosen = "<?php echo $_POST['durationChosen']?>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var postDuration = '<?php echo $_POST['durationChosen']; ?>';
</script>
```

Just echo it into the Javascript on the page, just like any other dynamic content.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple as...

```
var myVar = '<? echo $postduration; ?>';
```

Comment: if the duration is a number this will give him a string in JS

Comment: this way is better to avoid errors and it can be easy convert to number ex: myVar = myVar - 0;

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it into a javascript variable (jquery framework helps with DOM manipulation)

```
<?php  $postduration  = $_POST['durationChosen']; ?>

var myVar = '<?php echo $postduration ?>';
```